# Unity UI Image sprite (stretch) tiles when assigned from Texture2D at runtime (?)

Tags: unity-ui

For some reason a Unity UI Image that is set to stretch becomes tiled when assigned from Texture2D at runtime (?)

Comment: Can you edit your question to walk us through creating a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of this issue? What specific code are you using, and how have you set up the objects it acts upon?

Comment: This question needs more examples and context.